# GET Spell Checker/Correction API?

Tags: php, api, get, spell-checking

I have done a lot of research, and found nothing, but does anyone know of a spell checker API?

So when you send a request to `http://spellcheck.com?spellcheck-api=this is a sentnse`, and it returns `this is a sentence`.

Please, tell me how to make my question better in the comments without downgrading, I'll fix it as fast as possible. I am a new SO member.

Comment: You described a *correction* API, not a spellcheck API.

Comment: http://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/?q=spell

Comment: Most of them either don't work or aren't free.

Answer (score 3):

Check this awesome script: http://www.phpspellcheck.com

What you practically do is just fetch your `$_GET['spellcheck_api']` (convert `%20`'s if needed to spaces). And let the script (`include()` or `require()`) handle check your string for spelling errors.

Good luck !

Comment: The website doesn't load for me.